# Using different git users for different repositories on same machine

Tags: git, github

I need to know the best practice of using different git users for different local repositories on a same machine.
For example:- I have one git user for the work project and another private git user for personal stuff. Each time I go for a different user I first need to remove the existing git user credentials from the generic credential manager on windows and then login into another git user, otherwise I end up using only one user for everything.

Answer (score 2):

The Git FAQ outlines how to do this with both HTTPS and SSH.  [For HTTPS](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingHTTP), you use the username in the URL, and [for SSH](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingSSH), you use different aliases for your `~/.ssh/config` file, which you then use in your URL instead of the hostname.  The HTTPS approach is typically easier to implement.